# SignalR-Implementing SignalA client is not working in Android

Tags: signalr

I have downloaded signalR client for android from github which is SignalA. but i cant able import SignalA.longPolling project in eclipse. Can anybody tell me what is the problem? I have just downloaded the repository from github and importing but its not wroking.

Answer (score 0):

SignalA uses Android Studio and Gradle. The source is not compatible with Eclipse anymore. Maybe you can use maven to include SignalA in your project instead?!

Comment: Thanks for the information Erik, rite now i am using SignalR client for my eclipse and its working.

Comment: can you give some code for implementing with SignalA..??

Comment: Ofcourse, have a look here https://github.com/erizet/SignalA and look at the demos.

Comment: @pankaj716 Could you please share some code of signalR integration in native android in eclipse?